Clustering standard errors with a random effects model?
I am assessing the relation between unemployment (X) and drunk driving arrests per capita (Y). I have a panel of 2000 counties with t=15.
I am running a random effects model with the plm package on r. Is it possible to cluster the SEs at the county level?

Seems possible...see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512566/7623302.
